# How to grab mouse on Windows

Tags: c, windows, gtk, cross-platform, mouse

I'm writing a cross-platform application that on certain condition takes control of all user input for a period of time.

On GNU/Linux I've used gtk+, which allows me to retrieve mouse and keyboard events such as movement or presses. That's something I need as my application responds to them. It has also a small graphical interfce created with gtk+.

I've been trying to grab mouse input on Windows without success as gtk does work well graphically, but does not grab user input. I've tried using BlockIntput() but it does not works as expected because:

1. I need administrator priviledges to run the application
2. I can't read mouse nor keyboard input

Is there a way to grab mouse and keyboard input on windows and still being able to read their inputs without administrative rights?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789883/grab-exclusively-release-mouse-in-application-windows-c Or even this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645533(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a solution that fits my requirements. One of Marc's links guided me to the use of hooks on Windows which I had already tried with no success, but I ended up implementing them for both keyboard and mouse grabbing.

My Windows code uses windows libraries and when I need to block input I create a thread which calls a function:

```
    DWORD dwThread;
    CreateThread(NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)MouseHooker, NULL, 0, &dwThread);
```

Then I install the hook:

```
DWORD WINAPI MouseHooker(LPVOID lpParameter) {
HINSTANCE hExe = GetModuleHandle(NULL);

//The thread's parameter is the first command line argument which is the path to our executable.
if (!hExe) //If it fails we will try to actually load ourselves as a library.
    hExe = LoadLibrary((LPCSTR) lpParameter);
if (!hExe)
    return 1;
//Install the hook as a low level mouse hook thats calls mouseEvent
hMouseHook = SetWindowsHookEx (WH_MOUSE_LL, (HOOKPROC)MouseEvent, hExe, 0);
...
UnhookWindowsHookEx(hMouseHook);
return 0;
```

}

And on each mouse event code gets called:

```
if  (nCode == HC_ACTION && ...) { //HC_ACTION means we may process this event, we may add specific mouse events
    //We block mouse input here and do our thing
}
//return CallNextHookEx(hKeyHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
return 1;
```

So as we not continue with the hook chain input never gets processed and the workstation gets blocked.

The code runs on Windows 7 as expected. I kept using gtk+ on Windows as I can still generate my GUI and retrieve mouse inputs with gdk.
On GNU/Linux code works only using GTK+ libraries as I had no issues when grabbing input.

Comment: could you show a pure C example how you captured keyboard input?